# JQuery Comment system is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make comment system, the issue that the comment didn't show up , and if it did then the vote and username and other items didn't show up

The vote button is working

I don't what is the issue here?

https://codepen.io/MRuhaily/pen/OoNRQp

[image]
HTML

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.upvote').on('click', function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      var counter = 0;
      counter = counter + 1;
      $('.votes').html(counter);

    });
  });

  $('.downvote').on('click', function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      var counter = 0;
      counter = counter - 1;
      $('.votes').html(counter);

    });
  });

  $('#addCommentButtton').on('click', function(e) {
    var comment = $('#commentText').val();
    $('<li>').text(comment).prependTo('.Comments');
    $('#commentDiv').val('');

    if (comment.length > 1) {
      $('#addCommentButtton[type="submit"]').removeClass('disabled');
    } else if (comment.length === 0) {
      $('#addCommentButtton[type="submit"]').addClass('disabled');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: You write `The vote button is working` do you mean **is** or **is not** working? Because if the vote button is working for you then what is the problem. What should the red marking show? And in your codepen demo nothing works.

Comment: there is nothing working in your pen link

Comment: Are you sure you have included JQuery in your CodePen?

Comment: @SapuSeven yes the OP is missing jQuery in the example, but even if jQuery is added nothing the OP has posted works. The voting system won't work, and the comment won't work either.

Comment: Why are you attaching the click events twice on .upvote and .downvote elements. You can arrange the code like the following example: $('.upvote').on('click', function() {
  var counter = parseInt($('.votes').text());
  counter = !isNaN(counter )? (counter + 1) : 1;
  $('.votes').html(counter);
});

Comment: @t.niese For me at least voting seems to _kind of_ work after I add JQuery

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question, including HTML and CSS. Preferably as a [MCVE]

Comment: @Manoz sorry I added the jquery, now the button is working

Comment: @t.niese the vote does work , comment is not

Answer (score 1):

The button type is `submit` so the default behaviour is to submit the form.

You have to add `e.preventDefault()` to the callback function:

```
$('#addCommentButtton').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // rest of the code
})
```

That way the form will not be submitted, and the page won't be reloaded. Beside that the textarea has the id `commentDiv` and not `commentText` so it has to be:

```
var comment = $('#commentDiv').val();
```

The voting is also broken, but as you say it works like you want and your question is about the comment I won't target that problem. And it is also mentioned in the comment what you did wrong with the voting.

Comment: Thanks, the comment did showup, but still the vote buttons and username didn't show up with the comment. and please if you could help with comment I've hard time trying to fix it.